# Update a data holding class from another assembly without making it public accessible

Tags: c#, .net, builder

I'm working on a project for automating the execution of tests done by another program. Therefore, I have a class holding information about different test suites (basically categories) and each test suite holds tests.

The files containing the test information are either on the same computer as the program or must be accessed via SSH, which is why I have two different classes to fill the TestSuitesInfo container class.

These two classes are in seperate assemblies, so I created an update interface which passes the TestSuiteInfo object to an update method:

```
public interface ITestSuitesUpdater
{
    void Update(TestSuitesInfo info);
}
```

The problem here is that someone could store the reference to the TestSuiteInfo object and modify it when the update method is not called.

My first approach to a solution was to create a bool indicating if the object is updateable and throw an AccessViolationException if it isn't. However, it simply didn't look right to me:

```
public class TestSuitesInfo
{
    private IDictionary<string, TestSuite> _testSuites;
    private bool _updateable = false;

    internal TestSuitesInfo(IDictionary<string, TestSuite> dictionary)
    {
        _testSuites = dictionary;
    }

    public void AddTestSuite(string name)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));

        if (!_updateable)
            throw new AccessViolationException("TestSuiteInfo already created!");

        if (_testSuites.ContainsKey(name))
            return;

        _testSuites.Add(name, new TestSuite(name));
    }
...
}
```

I ended up writing a TestSuitesInfoBuilder class and passing that instead of the TestSuitesInfo itself, which makes me creating a new instance of TestSuitesInfo every time the update method get's called.

Now, I'm still curious if there is a better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put [this attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on the class whose internals need to be visible to the test project:

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestAssemblyName)]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but in that case everything set internal would be visible to the other assembly, which is not a solution in my case